# Base64 decode string in Android

Tags: android, base64

I am trying to encode and decode a String using android.util.Base64, but it gives a bad base-64 error.

```
String str = "EOKF36syRBtB11VgyChkNjc1HxRrajT7XXaxZfnVzPkV57K3b9yqkS284Ovb9uWzXgGeY2bxA3IySGfdOHiPAQ==F/v6hcTiU1sd975XHfDsz8o0rboujM77n7KwRMidobOLbo5ghUT/IFcxElUc8CirdZxaCaS3zs/CfRKRsXwbFNYd";
Base64.decode(str,Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

I am trying to decode the string using the following flags (NO_CLOSE, DEFAULT, NO_PADDING, URL_SAFE) but it give the same error.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Rule #1 of Android debugging: _always_ paste your error if you want to receive good answers. I tested here and I receive a `Base64DecoderException` with message _encoded getValue has invalid trailing byte_, which means that the chunk being decoded at the time isn't finalized by an equal sign (`61`) or new line (`10`) byte. If it is really worth it—or want to learn more—you can debug/breakpoint what is being done in the `Base64` class and also see the Base64 spec online.

Comment: Make sure you don't have space between your string. that may give you bad string error.

Answer (score 7):

I use below method for decoding base64 strings and it works fine.

```
private String decodeBase64(String coded){
    byte[] valueDecoded= new byte[0];
    try {
        valueDecoded = Base64.decode(coded.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
    return new String(valueDecoded);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your encoded string seems to be corrupted. Try decoding the string you have defined in the variable 'str' using an online base64 decoder. The result is garbled text.

Comment: Without more details this seems to be the best we can answer.

Answer (score 1):

Place a correct base64 String and try like below

```
    String img = "your_base_64_string";
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```